# ¿Guardar valor de arreglo al iterar? en angular js

Tags: angular

itero en un arreglo de datos traídos de mysql

```
    <div class="card shadow border-0" style="height: 400px;" *ngFor="let eq of equipo">
    <h3 >{{eq.Equipos_idEquipos}}</h3>  ====> Esto es lo que quiero guardar en una variable
                                               y usarla en el controlador
    </div>
```

Comment: pero si ya lo tienes en el array que estas iterando. Puedes ser mas explicito porfavor

Comment: lo que quiero es capturar ese valor que estoy imprimiendo {{eq.Equipos_idEquipos}} para volver a enviarlo a mi api y relizar una nueva consulta....

Comment: pero habrá alguna acción del usuario(por ejemplo click) que desencadenará la petición  a la api con ese id? Porque sino no lo entiendo y asi no puedo ayudar